# python linkedlist remove tuples

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

I need help with the remove function. Can't remove the element ("B",2). If someone could show me how mine is wrong, or write me a new one I'd be ever so grateful.

```
class LinkedList:
def __init__(self, data= [(None,None)],number = None, letter = None,  tail = None):
    self.letter = data[0][0]
    self.number = data[0][1]
    self.tail = None if (len(data) == 1) else LinkedList(data[1:])


def insert(self, val):
    new = LinkedList(val)
    new.tail = self.tail 
    self.tail = new 

def printer(self,curr):
    while curr:
        if curr.number is not None: print(curr.letter, curr.number)
        curr = curr.tail

def remove(self, item):
    if item == self.tail:
        self.tail = self.tail.tail
        return
    previous = self.tail
    current = self.tail.tail #i.e. current is set one in front
    while current:
        if current == item:
            previous.tail = current.tail
            return
        previous = current
        current = current.tail
new = LinkedList()

new.insert([("A", 1)])
new.insert([("B", 2)])
new.insert([("C", 3)])
new.printer(new)
print("---------")
new.remove([("B", 2)])
new.printer(new)
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Where have you narrowed the problem down to?

Comment: I'm not at the stage of knowing what debugging is. All I know is it runs without error, but does not remove the required element.

Comment: This would be an excellent place to start. Step though the `remove` method line by line. Think about what you expect to happen after each line runs, then check to see what actually happened. That is, at the core, how you debug. It's one of the most important skills you can have as a programmer; even more important than understanding how a linked list works.